# How do I get checkbox unchecked from rowselection in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs

I am using checkboxselectionmodel in  ExtJS grid?

when i clicked on the row the row get selected and the respective checkbox also checked ..

But i need the checkbox to be checked only when i click the checkbox otherwise i want row 
only get selected ...

Please help me out...

Thanks & Regards,

Ramanavel Selvaraju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CheckboxSelectionModel` links row selection and checkbox selection. You want row selection to be independent from the checkbox - so use `RowSelectionModel` and add a `Checkbox` into the first column of your grid.

Answer (score 2):

In your CheckboxSelectionModel set checkOnly config option to true.